# How to decipher zener diode encoding?

Tags: diodes, zener

I'm new to electronics and I'm trying to reverse engineer the circuit board in an R/C car. I've come across a diode and it is labelled...

```
C3V3
 5T
```

1) I assume `3V3` means 3.3V, but what do the `C` and `5T` mean?

2) Is the black stripe on the input or output side?

3) Is there a dead giveaway letting me know this is a "zener" diode? I ask because I've been web searching and all results turn up as a zener diode.

Comment: A close-up photo of the board would be good.

Comment: I cannot attach photos, I don't have a high enough rating... However, this is strictly a diode we are talking about.

Comment: The appearance of the diode, the typeface used, possible confusion over characters and possibly even the surrounding components, would give a clue as to what this is. For example, "5T" could actually be "ST", a manufacturer of diodes.

Comment: Maybe you could post a photo to somewhere you do have access to?

Comment: @gwideman It very well could be `ST` in a block style font. Also, I've been looking for photos and I can't find one to save my life.

Comment: You are almost certainly right that it is a 3.3V zener... we're narrowing down other specs.

Comment: OK, google image search for "zener diode", and find one of approximately the same appearance

Comment: Surface-mount or through-hole (wires on each end); Black plastic, metal, clear glass, or blue glass, or something else? About how large?

Comment: wires, red with black stripe on the end, black letters

Comment: By "red" do you mean copper colored enclosed in glass? Like: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/1N4746ATR/1N4746AFSCT-ND/1532759

Comment: Yes, after closer inspection, that is what I meant. :D

Comment: @Zak, just an FYI for next time - you should be able to post images directly. It used to need a rep of 10 (I think requirement has been removed) but either way you should be able to now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tentative answer.... iterating as OP adds more details...

... and adding details from the datasheet found by @Shantam

- 3V3 -- a zener of 3.3V
- C -- tolerance, probably 5%
- Stripe indicates cathode end of a diode. That's the end to which the arrow in the symbol points.
- ST -- SGS Thomson

Comment: Can you address why it should be obvious it is a "Zener" diode?

Comment: @Zak Because of the 3V3 marking. The forward/reverse bias voltage drop of most "regular" diodes is not a determining factor of their application, whereas Zeners are used exclusively for over-voltage protection or voltage regulation.

Comment: I imagine something like this is what you're looking at: http://www.datasheets360.com/pdf/-2117927204213530624

Comment: @Shantam Score! That's exactly what I was suspecting, but didn't find.

Comment: @Shantam -- and amusingly there's what appears to be a typo in that datasheet Electrical Characteristics table for the OP's device, which is listed as a "BZX 55 V 3V3" ... the only one with a V instead of a C.

Comment: @Zak Judging by the notes under the Electrical Characteristics table, the 'C' is an indication of tolerance on the voltage characteristic, since 'B' is shown to indicate +/-2%, and 'A' indicates 1%. 'C' is probably 5% -- the VZT/IZT column (probably should be VZT @ IZT) shows 3.1 to 3.5V for the 3V3. http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/AND8250-D.PDF shows a nice zener graph.

Comment: @Shantam Thank you for the awesome details! (gwideman) Will you please edit your answer to include the +1s from the comments.